# How power efficient are Apple's bluetooth devices?

Tags: keyboard, wifi, bluetooth, trackpad

I learned from [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4610/what-is-the-function-of-the-power-button-on-the-apple-wireless-keyboard) that I can hold the power button long enough to turn off the bluetooth keyboard.

I used Apple's bluetooth mouse around 5 years ago, and I just threw it away as it was a battery killer. Since then, I never have used bluetooth devices. Ironically, I use Microsoft wireless mouse which lasts months without battery change with Mac.

- How battery efficient are Apple's bluetooth devices? Normally, how long do you use Apple's bluetooth devices without battery change?
- Do I have to turn off bluetooth keyboard/trackpad whenever I don't use them? Do I have  serious battery drainage if I don't turn them off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a Magic Mouse and a Wireless keyboard, and I use rechargeable batteries. I charge them once a month, but I'm sure they'll last at least one more.

All the recent Apple wireless (Bluetooth) products are very smart about power usage and it really doesn't matter wether you turn them off or leave them on. I turn them off only when transporting them in my bag.

Note that the battery percentage reported for bluetooth devices is not accurate. It's based on the voltage of the cell, and since it's different in the Alkaline (1.5 V) and the Ni-MH rechargeable (1.3 V) batteries, it's virtually impossible to distinguish between the two. Not to mention the discharge curve of both.

Changes in 10.6.7 made it more accurate for devices, running on rechargeable batteries - It now treats charge around 1.3 V for 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a Magic Mouse shortly after it was released and used it heavily (8+ hours a day) for months until handing it off to my girlfriend, who's still using it on the original batteries. I'd say the battery usage is "near zero".

Sometimes, after being off for a weekend, the battery percentage has gone up. I know Steve says they haven't found out how to defy the laws of physics yet, but I think he's a liar.

Comment: I'm not sure if the original batteries could last for 1.5 years. With heavy use, my original batteries lasted maybe 1.5 months. And it has been the same for the last 9 months with different batteries also. I don't always turn the iMac nor the Magic Mouse off, e.g. for night.